# How can I switch Video element priority in which can be played and paused in JavaScript/Html

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

My game was not playing the other songs, so I'm looking for an example of how to change the audio.

Here's my HTML:

```
<body onload= myFunction() >
<video autoplay="true"  id="song" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/518000/518280_-Super-Battletrain-.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
<video autoplay="true"  id="song2" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/504000/504114_Flirt-Flirt-Oh-It-Hurts.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
<video autoplay="true"  id="song3" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="hhttp://audio.ngfiles.com/587000/587069_-Endgame-.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers will only play *one* file automatically. If you want to play multiple files at the same time, you need to use JavaScript, like this:

```html
<body onload="javascript:myFunction()">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myFunction = function() {
      document.getElementById('song').play();
      document.getElementById('song2').play();
      document.getElementById('song3').play();
    };
  </script>

  <video id="song" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/518000/518280_-Super-Battletrain-.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
  <video id="song2" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/504000/504114_Flirt-Flirt-Oh-It-Hurts.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
  <video id="song3" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="hhttp://audio.ngfiles.com/587000/587069_-Endgame-.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
  <p id="demo"></p>
   
</body>
```

You can also call `document.getElementById('song').pause()` to pause a song.

**EDIT**: to play one song after the other, you would do something like this:

```html
<body onload="javascript:myFunction()">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myFunction = function() {
      var song1 = document.getElementById('song');
      var song2 = document.getElementById('song2');
      var song3 = document.getElementById('song3');

      song1.play();

      song1.onpause = function() {
        song2.play();
      };

      song2.onpause = function() {
        song3.play();
      };

      song3.onpause = function() {
        song1.play();
      };
    };
  </script>

  <video id="song" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/518000/518280_-Super-Battletrain-.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
  <video id="song2" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="http://audio.ngfiles.com/504000/504114_Flirt-Flirt-Oh-It-Hurts.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
  <video id="song3" width="0" height="0" loop><source src="hhttp://audio.ngfiles.com/587000/587069_-Endgame-.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></video>
  <p id="demo"></p>
   
</body>
```

This will start playing song1, then when it is paused it will play song2, then song3, and then song1 again.

Comment: sorry I think I miss stated my question. It was helpful, but the problem was the first song was playing and after I paused it was suppose to play the second song but the song would not play

Comment: @MatthewSteger Ok, I've updated my answer with some more details on how to do what you want. You just need to subscribe to the `pause` event on each video element.